# Dart: Is it possible to pass a generic type to a class as a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have a class with a generic type and I want to pass that type as a variable.
Is there a way to achieve this?

```dart
abstract class MainType {}

class TypeA extends MainType {}

class TypeB extends MainType {}

class MyClass<T extends MainType> {}

Type getType(String key) {
  if (key == 'a') return TypeA;

  return TypeB;

}

MyClass constructMyObject(String key) {
  final type = getType(key);
  return MyClass<type>(); //<<-- This here doesn't work
}
```

The background is, that I want to parse the type from a string and pass that type to various classes.

Comment: What are the possible options for type?

Comment: Possible options for `type` would be `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as far as I understood this isn't possible without some workarounds.

One potential solution I found is the [type_plus package](https://pub.dev/packages/type_plus). But I haven't tried it.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
abstract class MainType {}

class TypeA extends MainType {}

class TypeB extends MainType {}

class MyClass<T extends MainType> {}

R decodeType<R>(String? key, R Function<T extends MainType>() builder) {
  if (key == 'a') return builder<TypeA>();

  return builder<TypeB>();
}

MyClass constructMyObject(String key) {
  // ignore: unnecessary_lambdas
  return decodeType(key, <T extends MainType>() => MyClass<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MyClass is not of type T so you can't return a MyClass object from it.

Is this what you want?

```
MyClass constructMyObject<T extends MainType>() {
  return MyClass<T>();
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. My example doesn’t represent what I want at all. I’ll edit it.