# Is it possible to create a List in Dart/Flutter using a variable as the type?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

Is it possible to assign a type to a variable and then use that to create a type-based object, such as a List?  My use case is that I have a Flutter widget using a particular data type to create a List for a FutureBuilder.  If I could parameterise the type rather than hard-coding it then I could re-use the widget for multiple data types.

I have tried to do this in DartPad as follows:

```
void main() {
  A a = A(int);
  a.stuff();
}

class A {
  A(Type type) {
    _type = type;
  }
  late Type _type;

  void stuff() {
    print('$_type');     // prints out 'int'
    List<_type> b = [];
  }
}
```

If I comment out the line `List<_type> b = [];` then the code works and the output is `int`.

However, if I include the List<> line then I get the error "The name '_type' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument."

If have found next to nothing on the internet about this so think it might not be possible.

I have also had a look at the question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476915/dart-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-generic-type-to-a-class-as-a-variable), which seems to be a similar question.  This uses generics, which I know nothing about, and I couldn't make it work in my case.  Is this a similar problem to mine and is it worth me doing some more exploration down this path?

My other idea was to pass a specific instance of the type that I want and then use `runtimeType` to get the type.  I have tried this in Dart and it also gives an error.

```
void main() {
  A a = A(1);
  a.stuff();
}

class A {
  A(this.value){}
  dynamic value;

  void stuff() {
    print('${value.runtimeType}');     // prints out 'int'
    List<value.runtimeType> b = [];
  }
}
```

If I comment out the List<> line then the code outputs `int`.

However, with the list line uncommented, it gives the error "'type.runtimeType' can't be used as a type because 'type' doesn't refer to an import prefix."

Does anyone know if it possible to do what I want?  Thanks.

Here is the full code for my use-case.  I have commented the line that I would like to be able to parameterise somehow so that I can re-use the widget for different data sets with the same structure.

```
import 'package:drift/drift.dart' as drift;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frequent/database/tables.dart';
import 'package:frequent/maintain/change_record_widget.dart';
import 'package:frequent/maintain/change_record.dart';

class MaintainInstruments extends StatefulWidget {
  MaintainInstruments({
    Key? key,
    required String title,
    required MyDatabase database,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    _title = title;
    _db = database;
  }

  late final String _title;
  late final MyDatabase _db;

  @override
  State<MaintainInstruments> createState() => _MaintainInstrumentsState();
}

class _MaintainInstrumentsState extends State<MaintainInstruments> {
  final double _width = 300;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          widget._title,
        ),
      ),
      //
      // Is it possible to parameterise the following statement so that I can
      // re-use this widget for a variety of data types that follow the same
      // format (id, name)?
      //
      body: FutureBuilder<List<InstrumentData>>(
        future: _getInstruments(widget._db),
        builder: (context, values) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                // color: Colors.blueGrey,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Table(
                defaultColumnWidth: const IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                children: [
                  TableRow(
                    children: [
                      TableCell(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 300,
                          width: _width,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: values.hasData ? values.data!.length : 0,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(values.data![index].name),
                                  tileColor: Colors.amber[200],
                                  hoverColor: Colors.amber[400],
                                  dense: true,
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  trailing: SizedBox(
                                    width: _width * 0.2,
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: IconButton(
                                            iconSize: 20,
                                            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              showDialog<Record>(
                                                context: context,
                                                builder:
                                                    (BuildContext context) {
                                                  return ChangeRecord(
                                                    record: Record.instrument(
                                                      id: values
                                                          .data![index].id,
                                                      instrument: values
                                                          .data![index].name,
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ).then((value) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _updateInstrument(
                                                      widget._db,
                                                      value!.id,
                                                      value.instrument);
                                                });
                                              });
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: IconButton(
                                            iconSize: 20,
                                            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _deleteInstrument(widget._db,
                                                    values.data![index].id);
                                              });
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ), // Just to track mouse over cards
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<InstrumentData>> _getInstruments(MyDatabase db) async {
  List<InstrumentData> values = await (db.select(db.instrument)
        ..orderBy([(t) => drift.OrderingTerm(expression: t.name)]))
      .get();
  return values;
}

void _deleteInstrument(MyDatabase db, int id) {
  (db.delete(db.instrument)..where((tbl) => tbl.id.equals(id))).go();
}

_updateInstrument(MyDatabase db, int id, String value) {
  (db.update(db.instrument)..where((tbl) => tbl.id.equals(id)))
      .write(InstrumentCompanion(name: drift.Value(value)));
}
```

Comment: you are getting error because you are doing it wrong. it should be `List<Type>`.  inside that bracket is a `type annotation` not an instance.

Comment: Sure, I get that. My question isn't, "why am I getting this error?" It is, "can you define the type at run time rather than at compile time, for example by using a variable?" (or using a design pattern  etc.)

Comment: of course you can. by assigning a variable to a type of 'var` you are saying that the compiler will give an explicit type on run time. take note that dart is a strongly typed language. and you can not run a variable without giving a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart supports generic types. SO you can do something like

```
class A<T> {

  void stuff() {
    List<T> b = [];
  }
}
```

And use it as

```
A<int>, A<String>
```

whatever type you need

Comment: Thanks for rhe quick response, but I don't think that answers my question.  If I create a variable Type t and use that in A<t> I get the same error as I do in the first example above, i.e. "The name 't' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument."  If I use 'T' in my Flutter code for the FutureBuilder (FutureBuilder<List<T>>) then I get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the code for error you got with generic types

Comment: This is the message in Visual Studio Code: "The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'T'. dart(non_type_as_type_argument)"

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have added my flutter code for my use case.  I have added a comment to highlight the line that my question relates to.

Comment: You can re-use the widget made with generic types also right?

Comment: I guess so.  I was just wondering if it was possible to pass it as a parameter, but I suppose that is what generics do just in a syntactically different way.

Comment: @Twelve1110 yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

you can use generics as this example :

```
class A<T> {
  List<T> stuff() {
    List<T> b = [];
    return b;
  }
}
```

then when you want to call this :

```
A a = A<int>();
List c = a.stuff();
```

this is a simple demo to understand the generic.